# An integer optimization problem on the simplex

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

For $K \geq n$ and some $\sigma_i > 0$, I am looking for a solution to the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\underset{\begin{smallmatrix} t_1, \cdots, t_n \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \\ \sum_{i=1}^{n} t_i = K\end{smallmatrix}}{\operatorname{min}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\sigma_i^2}{t_i}
\end{equation}

When we relax this problem as $t_i \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$, the solution is straightforward and given by $t_i = K \sigma_i / (\sum_j \sigma_j)$ but is there a close form solution in the case of integer programming?

It seems also that this problem is related to the "Optimal design" problem and maybe there are greedy algorithms.